# "We've determined that you have" or "We've determined you have" - and why?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

Apologies if this is an existing question. I am not familiar with the terminology required to tag this appropriately or come up with keywords for the search. Something along the lines of accusative case or what have you.

Perhaps this is a simple case of style.

Take these two sentences;

> We've determined that you have previously visited Elbonia.

and

> We've determined you have previously visited Elbonia.

Which is the correct structure, and why?

Comment: @user405662 Thanks. I now know what its called. This would probably be a suitable answer.

Comment: "That" is optional but preferable in your example. The version without it tends to be more informal.

Comment: Please check the edited answer @speciesUnknown. And apologies for my previous answer, which was clearly wrong.

Comment: This is a lot more complicated than I initially thought. But yes, the new answer makes sense.

Comment: @speciesUnknown It's really not complicated. In _that_ clauses the word "that" is generally optional. The main place where "that" is obligatory is where the content clause is subject of the matrix clause, as in "[That I need help] is clear". And it's inadmissible in a clause that is complement to a preposition like "before". We can't say *"I left before [that he arrived]". Elsewhere, it is generally optional.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that this is more an issue of style than of grammar. Both your sentences are correct, with the first being more formal than the second.

Grammar-wise, the clause *that you've previously visited Elbonia* is a noun clause and it functions as the *object* of the transitive verb *have determined.*

Comment: How can it be a 'reduced relative clause' when it's not even a relative clause. Relative clauses (including the so-called 'reduced' kind) are modifiers in NP structure, but both the OP's examples are declarative content clauses functioning as **complement** of the verb "determined".

Comment: Yes, I agree that my answer is totally flawed. Editing it. Thanks a lot, @BillJ.